# Excel VBA to see if a workbook is open and if is write data

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to see if an excel workbook is open (Logtemplate.xlsm)using HP 
     Reflections VBA.And if the workbook is open on my desktop,then sendthe
     Text from Reflections to the next available row on that workbook.
     I can get the excel workbook to open, but it will only update the Text one
     time, and the next time I try to run the vba it reopens the same excel 
     file and doesn't update the Text.  I'm very new to VBA and any help 
     would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

---

```
Sub Test()
On Error GoTo 0

With Session

Wait 1

Dim Text As String
Dim TopRow, LastRow, LastColumn As Integer
Dim excelApp As Object
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim eRow As Long

TopRow = .ScreenTopRow
LastRow = TopRow + .DisplayRows
LastColumn = .DisplayColumns

Text = .GetText(.CursorRow - 1, 0, .CursorRow, 125)


On Error GoTo 0
Set wb = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
Set wb = Workbooks("Logtemplate.xlsm")

On Error GoTo 0

If wb Is Nothing Then
Set excelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
excelApp.Visible = True
Set excelApp = Workbooks.Open("C:\Logtemplate.xlsm")
excelApp.Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
excelApp.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Select
eRow = excelApp.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End (xlUp).Offset  (1, 0).Row

Cells(eRow + 1, 1).Select
Cells(eRow, 1).Value = Text


On Error Resume Next

If Not wb("Logtemplate.xlsm") Is Nothing Then
Set excelApp = Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
End If
On Error Resume Next
excelApp.Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
excelApp.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Select
eRow = excelApp.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End (xlUp).Offset (1, 0).Row
Cells(eRow + 1, 1).Select
Cells(eRow, 1).Value = Text


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with **Excel VBA** you don't need to create an excel application object. It's already available to you. code below will give you al the open workbooks:

```
Dim oWB As Workbook

For Each oWB In Workbooks

    MsgBox oWB.Name

Next

Set oWB = Nothing
```

I've put a `MsgBox` just to give you an idea on how to get workbook name. you can use that to check if you expected workbook is already open. Give this a go and see if your updates work. If not post back and I'll try to help

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  The vba is in HP Reflections (Attachmate) and it calls excel as an object.  My problem is I can't get the vba to determine if excel workbook is already open...and if it is resume sending Text (as .GetText) from Reflections.